# Compile error when huge Dictionary object. Breaking up the expression

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, compiler-errors

I'm creating a huge Dictionary object (About 300 keys) in my project, everything was working alright until a new compile error appears.

"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

I did what alert suggested me and I broke up the dictionary in 2 parts, then in 3, now in 4 but the silly compile error is still there.

The error wasn't there when the Dictionary was 250 keys, but now it is even with Dictionary objects with 30 lines, so yeah I don't know how to solve this issue. Additionally it makes me think that it's probably a bug.

```
let returnThing_2: [String:AvroValue] = [
            "record_xx" : AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
                "key_a" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
                "key_b" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
                "key_c" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
                "key_d" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
                "key_e" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
                 etc...
```

An `AvroValue."Whatever" = AvroValue`. Is not relevant at all in this context what is an AvroValue, as the Dictionary object is define to hold it "`[String:AvroValue]`".

This works properly but sometimes, the compiler requires too much time in the "type-check" process even if the Dictionary object is smaller thatn others without this issue.

[image]

**Until now, this is the only solution**
Declaring the objects in separate lines as the people in in the comments requested:

```
let dicti: [String:AvroValue] = [
    "key_a" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
        "key_b" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
        "key_c" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
        "key_d" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
        "key_e" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
         etc...
        ])
]
```

then, I add dicti into avroRecordValue:

```
let recordValue: AvroValue = AvroValue.avroRecordValue(dicti)
```

And finally:

```
let returnThing_2: [String:AvroValue] = [ "record_xx" : recordValue]
```

Comment: Try setting the resulting type explicitly

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm already setting the type of the variable to [String:AvroValue]. Where else do you think we should specify the type? I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the "resulting type".

Comment: Yes `let dict: [String: Value] =` ... whatever

Comment: @LeoDabus As you can see that's already sorted. The object "returnThing_2" is set as [String: AvroValue]

Comment: Is there any way to generate the key-value pairs it according to what you want?

Comment: can't you set your inner value `AvroValue.avroRecordValue` in a separate line ? Can you show its declaration?

Comment: RenzoTissoni, LeoDabus just modified the question to show how it would like like if I declare every object separately. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the 'error', based on [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time/), yet much longer:

[image]

I believe Swift type inference performance has been improved, but it cannot infer types for very complex types.

You probably need to separate nested dictionary inside:

```swift
AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
  "key_a" : AvroValue.avroIntValue(int32),
  ...
])
```

to a separate value, e.g., `let inner: [String: Int] = ["key_a": ...]`.

Or perhaps you can generate the values from some logic.
If it is very large, you should consider using a database (or save it elsewhere in a JSON format) and decode it before using it.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like something that makes sense. In fact, I've tried to create the dictionary that is inside of avroRecordValue() previously and it worked. However I'm still asking my self, why specifically with this object and not with the others, which are bigger.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as accepted, as it doesn't seems to exist a better solution, however, maybe it's possible to set the compile time to higher number?